# How do a group of developers fix multiple bugs in a previous release version via mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, workflow

Okay, [you fine people answered my question quite nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678855/how-do-i-fix-a-bug-in-a-previous-release-version-via-mercurial) and I'm thankful.

However, now I realize that it wasn't quite the right question so I have another (though I do think that the previous question will prove useful to others).

As before, we are using mercurial in a single repository. We have a master branch and a develop branch (as well as feature branches, but they aren't germane to the issue at hand).

We tag the master branch with releases (5.1.0.102, etc). We do our development on develop.

What I really want to do is to have a number of different fixes be bunched together off of a previous release in order to create a maintenance release that is a collection of fixes.

Or, put as before, here is what I really need:

1. Update to the point where we released (say 6.1.1) in a way that a group of developers can work together
2. That group of developer fixes a bunch of bugs.
3. Label that resulting code state as (6.1.2)
4. Do a build of this new 6.1.2 codebase.
5. Migrate those fixes into the develop branch
6. Do this in such a way that I can go back to 6.1.2 and fix bugs there if need be

Or, I need to create a maintenance release based on a previous release with work included from various developers.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer to the question you previously asked still holds, and the way you outline it in the question is ... well... the right way to do it.

So basically I don't understand what or why you're asking.

Here's what you should do.

1. One of the developers starts the job by updating back to the focal point of the last release (ie. the changeset of your 6.1.1 release)
2. He then makes some changes relevant to the bugfixes, commits, and pushes back to the central repository. Note that this will create another head. This is fine (see below if it isn't)
3. The other developers on his Tiger Team pull, and update to this new head, and add their contributions to the bugfixes, committing and pushing/pulling as needed
4. At some point, you have a new version, like 6.1.2, so you create a tag for the final changeset
5. You then update to the previous head (the one you had before you started this whole job) and merge in the 6.1.2 head, this brings all those bugfixes back into the main branch for future versions

It would look like this:

[image: bugfix in older version]

R5 here would be the merge commit, and R4 would be the current head if you disregard all the bugfixes that went into 6.1.2.

Then, if you want to come back to fix some more to get out a 6.1.3 version, it would look like this (you follow the exact same plan as above):

[image: more bugfixes]

Here R9 would be the current head of the next major version of your project, and R10 would be the merge commit that brought the bugfixes that went into 6.1.3 back into that future version.

Comment: Lasee -- thanks very much for your excellent answer.  One question: "The other developers on his Tiger Team pull, and update to this new head"  I assume that the other developers would have to do this update via the hex code name of the nameless branch?  And if so, would it be possible to go the easier route of naming the branch?

Comment: Well, yes, and no. If you want to know what I would do... I would create a separate "central repository clone" for their bugfix stint, and scrape out everything they don't need from there. If they require large portions of other branches, then ... perhaps a named branch is a good way to handle this, but personally I don't like named branches, they tend to be misused, and they're permanent. There's new bookmark support in the latest versions of Mercurial, but I've yet to experiment properly with it, but perhaps that would help you, creating a temporary "branch name" so to speak.

Comment: In other words, unless they need changesets after 6.1.1, I would clone up to and including the 6.1.1 changeset, but not beyond, and that would be the repository clone the Tiger Team would work from. In this case, the tip of the repository would match their progress.

Comment: Lasse -- Thanks very much.  Very helpful and on point.  I'm grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Your steps are almost right. My suggestion is this:

1. Use the main trunk as a development branch
2. When you need to release you create a new branch
3. All the bug fixing is done on the new branch for 1-2 days before is stable
4. You make the launch
5. You merge the release with the devel trunk
6. If critical bugs found go to step 1.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Workflow for this on the Git side, called [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). This tool essentially automates a lot of the tedium involved (create a branch off your production-stable branch, commit commit, merge branch to where your new current work is).

There is a Mercurial extension that gives you that exact workflow for Hg: [Hg Flow](https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/hgflow/wiki/Home). I've used it (although not for a big app) and I really like it - it automates the steps involed just like Git Flow does, and brings the wisdom from the Git community over to Hg-land.

Comment: Can this be run "after the fact" -- i.e., on an existing repository?

Comment: Yup. I've moved an existing repo to Hg Flow and it Just Worked